# Authentication failed for bitbucket repository with app password

Tags: git, bitbucket

While trying to deploy project on EC2 instance using Capistrano script getting following error:

```
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xx.xxx.xx.xxx: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://UserName:UserPassword@bitbucket.org/Repo/repo.git/'
error: Could not fetch origin
```

How to change password in URL used to fetch origin?

Answer (score 0):

Change url path in **/home/ubuntu/git/repo/config** file on EC2 instance with new app password as follows:

```
url = https://UserName:NewAppPassword@bitbucket.org/User/repo.git/
```